# Processing saveFrame every 40 msec

Tags: processing

I'm trying to create a graphic synchronized with a video at 25 frames/sec. I'm trying to save one frame every 40 msec, but I can't get 25 frames per sec, but only one image.
Can someone help me?

```
int t1;
int count;

void setup(){
  size(400,100);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  fill(250);
  line(10,0,10,100);
  line(260,0,260,100);

  for (int i=10;i<251;i+=10){

    t1=millis();
    while(millis()-t1 < 40) {
      count++;
    }
    rect(10,50,i,10);
    //saveFrame("line-####.png");
  }
}

void draw(){}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that the canvas is updated only after the end of a frame, which means that your rectangles do exist but are not displayed until your *setup()* ends. This is why, even tho your code correctly waits 40 milliseconds before drawing a new rectangle, nothing is shown until the for loop ends: before ending the frame, Processing is waiting to complete the for loop.

However, in Processing *draw()* is called a certain amount of times per second, this amount of times is specified by the function *frameRate()* (default is 60).
Thus you can just set frameRate to 25 and save an image each time *draw()* is called.
*noLoop()* is used to stop calling *draw()*, in this case, once the rectangles are all drawn.

```
int count;

void setup()
{
  frameRate(25);
  size(400,100);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  fill(250);
  line(10,0,10,100);
  line(260,0,260,100);
}

void draw()
{
  rect(10,50,count,10);
  saveFrame("line-####.png");
  count += 10;
  if(count > 251)
  {
    noLoop();
  }
}
```